# GDB remote debugging fails with error E01

Tags: gdb, arm, cross-platform, gdbserver

I use this (http://cs.baylor.edu/~donahoo/tools/gdb/tutorial.html) guide to learn how GDB works. 
After compiling and uploading the code to my embedded linux arm platform I use a remote connection to connect with the gdbserver on my target:

Target:

```
root@zedboard-zynq7:/Software# gdbserver HOST:1234 broken
Process broken created; pid = 1103
Listening on port 1234
Remote debugging from host 192.168.178.32
```

Host (Ubuntu 14.04 running in a virtual machine):

```
Remote debugging using 192.168.178.33:1234
warning: A handler for the OS ABI "GNU/Linux" is not built into this   
configuration of GDB.  Attempting to continue with the default arm settings.

Cannot access memory at address 0x0
0x43330d40 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

I set the breakpoint to line 43 and continue the program until it stops at the breakpoint:

```
(gdb) b 43
Breakpoint 1 at 0x8b68: file broken.cpp, line 43.
(gdb) continue
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, main () at broken.cpp:43
43    double seriesValue = ComputeSeriesValue(x, n);
(gdb)
```

But after a step call on my host I got this error:
Host:

```
warning: Remote failure reply: E01
Ignoring packet error, continuing...
```

Target:

```
ptrace: Input/output error.
input_interrupt, count = 1 c = 36 ('$')
```

What does it mean and how can I fix it?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Host (Ubuntu 14.04 running in a virtual machine):
>
> ```
> Remote debugging using 192.168.178.33:1234
> warning: A handler for the OS ABI "GNU/Linux" is not built into this   
> configuration of GDB.  Attempting to continue with the default arm settings.`
> ```

This says that your (host) GDB has not been built with support for the target you want to debug.

> What does it mean and how can I fix it?

You need to either get a different build of (host) GDB, or build one yourself with correct `--target` setting.

*Usually* a correct host GDB is included with the cross-gcc that you use to build for your target. So a fix may be as simple as running `/path/to/cross-gdb` instead of `gdb`.

Comment: Thanks. It was the corrent hint. Seems that arm-none-eabi-gdb doesn´t work with my current compiler.
By using

bitbake gdb-cross

you can create a working gdb version for your cross compiler.