# How to debug an ARM Linux device with VSCode on a Windows host

Tags: visual-studio-code, arm, gdb, cross-platform, gdbserver

I try to remote debug an ARM Linux embedded device with Native Debug in VSCode on a Windows host (no WSL).

Host launch.json

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "gdb",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "gdb",
            "executable": "${workspaceRoot}\\myprogram\\myprogram ",
            "stopAtConnect": true,
            "target": "192.168.xxx.xxx:2000",
            "remote": true,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/myprogram", 
            "gdbpath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb-multiarch.exe",
            "debugger_args": ["-iex", "set osabi none"],
        }
    ]
}
```

Target

```bash
debarm:~# gdbserver --version                                         
GNU gdbserver (GDB) 7.0.1-debian                                      
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.                     
gdbserver is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License.
This gdbserver was configured as "arm-linux-gnueabi"                  
debarm:~# gdbserver :2000 --attach 1966                               
Attached; pid = 1966                                                  
Listening on port 2000                                                
Remote debugging from host 192.168.xxx.xxx
```

However, stepping gives `warning: Remote failure reply: E01` similar to: [GDB remote debugging fails with error E01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39692161/gdb-remote-debugging-fails-with-error-e01)

I also tried the `arm-none-eabi-gdb.exe` from https://developer.arm.com/downloads/-/gnu-rm but it gives the same problem.

I also tried the `arm-linux-gnueabi-gdb.exe` from https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest-5/arm-linux-gnueabi/ but it gives `Error while reading shared library symbols for target:/lib/ld-linux.so.3`.

Any suggestions for what the problem is with this approach?

Comment: Did you see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72342799/1983398)?

Comment: Yea saw it, but now you mention it I checked the following; `uname --m` on target gives `armv5tejl` and when I add `set architecture armv5tej` to the host `debugger_args` the problem persists.

Comment: This answer suggests that the used gdb can only debug intel architectures. Is `armv5tej` in the list of valid arguments if you enter `set architecture`?

Comment: Yes, `set architecture` in `gdb-multiarch.exe` lists `armv5tej`.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with Linaro `arm-linux-gnueabi-gdb.exe` and adding `"-iex", "set auto-solib-add 0"` to `debugger_args` in `launch.json`.